# Let $A$ be a complex $3 \times 3$ matrix with $A^3 = -I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Let $A$ be a complex $3 \times 3$ matrix with $A^3 = -I$. Which of the following statements are correct?

1. $A$ has three distinct eigenvalues.
2. $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$.
3. $A$ ls triangularizable over $\mathbb{C}$.
4. $A$ is non-singular.

If we take $A = -I$, then $A^3 = -I$ and has eigenvalues as $-1, -1, -1$. so option $1$ is incorrect. Since $A$ is not equal to $0$, $A$ is non-singular and also option $2$ and $3$ are correct. Hence option $2, 3$, and should be options. Is it correct?

Comment: is it $A^3=-I$ $?$

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, please fix typos.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you answer 1) is correct.

2) Using the Julien's hint, let $p(x)=x^3+1$ then this polynomial with distinct roots in $\mathbb C$ annihilates the matrix $A$ and then this matrix is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$.

3) Every matrix is trigonalizable over $\mathbb C$

4) We have $\det(A)^3=\det(A^3)=\det(-I)=-1\neq 0$ so $A$ is invertible.

Comment: For my benefit, what does it mean by saying "Every matrix is trigonalizable over C"

Comment: I don't understand if I made a mistake in the term  "trigonalizable" or you ask for the meaning of the result.

Comment: meaning of the result, please.

Comment: It means simply that every matrix $A$ is similar to a triangular matrix $T$ over $\mathbb C$ (i.e there's an invertible matrix such that $A=PTP^{-1}$ ) and in fact in any field $\mathbb F$ A matrix is ​​trigonalizable if and only if its characteristic polynomial splits in $\mathbb F[x]$.

Comment: Ok cool, when you saying "over C" it means that the entries of the matrix are complex, correct?

Comment: Yes correct which is an algebraically closed field.

Comment: Well-written, Sami!

Answer (score 0):

Diagonalizable means the matrix has three distinct eigenvectors.

We cannot infer that the minimal polynomial is $\lambda^3+1=0$.

So, I think 2) might be incorrect.

For 1) 3) 4) I agree with Sami Ben Romdhane.

Comment: No, 2 is correct. The minimal polynomial divides $X^3+1$, which is enough.